# Unable to get responsive sprite using css

Tags: css, sass, sprite

I'm trying to build a responsive website especially using a sprite split by 8 different images. I assume the usual way to make an image responsive is using css like below:

```
CSS:
  div {
     width: 25%;

 img {
    max-width:100%;
     }
}
```

But the issue is that I can't find a way to make my sprite responsive since the img is set as a background of a div and the adjustment is not set dynamically.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

Comment: There's still an issue with the height assuming an element with a background image/sprite will not adjust its height the same way a simple image could do.